# Fetch all the childrens of a node with their tags

Tags: java, xpath

I need to fetch all the childrens of a node with their tags using xpath ,suppose i have a node

```
 <div id="topbar">
    <ul>
    <li>product No</li>
    <li>product name</li>
    <li>product details</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

then i want expected output as

```
<ul>
    <li>product No</li>
    <li>product name</li>
    <li>product details</li>
</ul>
```

I tried //div[@id='topbar']/node() it is returning the correct node with its childs

```
 XPath xpath1 = new DOMXPath(item.getXpathToExtractValue());
    Object itemObject = xpath1.selectSingleNode(element);
    if (itemObject instanceof Node)
      Node itemElement = (Node) itemObject;
```

and when i use itemElement.getNodeValue() it is returning product No product name product details  not the expected output.

Comment: You need something like: `itemElement.OuterXML`

Answer (score 0):

getNodeValue() returns the text content of a node. You need to transform the node into a string, e.g.:

```
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    TransformerFactory.newInstance()
        .newTransformer()
        .transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(writer));
    return writer.toString();
```

Comment: its not giving expected output for me .. still its giving text of first child node... :(